# get each row from datagrid in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a datagrid as shown below

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dataGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

<Columns>

    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal ID="names" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Status">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal ID="status" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>

</Columns>
```

I want to iterate through each row in datagrid, how can I do this?
I am using vb.net

thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the [DataGrid.ItemDatabound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx)-event?

Comment: @seph I want to get each row in a function.

Comment: @5uperdan I want to get rows not from datatable but from DataGrid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This.

```
foreach(DataGridItem dataGridItem in dataGrid1.Items)
{   
    Literal ltr = (Literal)dataGridItem.FindControl("names"); 
    string strName = ltr.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop for getting each rows in grid.

Also use Ctype getting grid view control.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To grdView.Rows.Count - 1

Status = CType(grdView.Rows(i).FindControl("status"), Literal).ToString

Next
```